# Add 'Done' button to keyboard using UI Toolbar

Tags: swift

I have text views that I want to be able to have a done button. I have added a UI toolbar and connected it as an outlet plus IB action for the done button

The toolbar is not showing up? what have I missed?

```
    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
     ingredientsTextField.inputAccessoryView
    = keyboardToolbar
    return true
}

@IBAction func didClickDoneButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    ingredientsTextField.endEditing(true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be your creation of toolbar is wrong, check this

```
 func textViewShouldBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) -> Bool {

        self.addAccessoryView()

        return true
    }


    func addAccessoryView() -> Void {
        let toolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 44))
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(self.doneButtonTapped(button:)))

        let flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)

        toolBar.items = [flexibleSpace,doneButton]
        toolBar.tintColor = UIColor.red

        self.textView.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    }
    func doneButtonTapped(button:UIBarButtonItem) -> Void {
        // do you stuff with done here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet looks fine! Did you set the delegate for your `textfield`? If you missed it please set it else `func textFieldShouldBeginEditing` will not be called!

Please find below working code for your reference,

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    internal func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        let numberToolbar = UIToolbar(frame:  CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 50))
        numberToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
        numberToolbar.items = [
            UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: Selector(("cancelNumberPad"))),
            UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil),
            UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: Selector(("doneWithNumberPad")))]
        numberToolbar.sizeToFit()
        textField.inputAccessoryView
            = numberToolbar
        return true
    }

    @IBAction func didClickDoneButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        textField.endEditing(true)
    }

    @IBAction func buttonClick(_ sender: Any) {
        textField.endEditing(true)
    }

}
```